# soapui soap digital signature

Tags: soap, digital-signature, soapui

I need to digitally sign a soap message in a client. A PEM file with both private key and certificate has been given to me. I thought to test with SoapUI.

Configuration for signature is done OK in Outgoing WS Security configuration - see the picture, as well,  pem is added OK in Keystore/Certificate tab, but the soap message sent to a service is not signed. 
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

[image: SoapUI configuration for signature]

Comment: One comment regarding the picture above. Parts configuration is wrong there. It should be like this: Body:  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Element This setup has worked for me. If selected Content as above, then received error: General security error (WSEncryptBody/WSSignEnvelope: Element to encrypt/sign not found: , Body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SOAP Request TestStep you have a tab called **Aut**. (First tab on the left)

There you have to add your Outgoing WSS Configuration.

See screenshot:

[image: soapUI Screenshot]