# Can soapUI access a windows stored certificate for digitally signing requests?

Tags: soap, soapui, digital-signature

I have the same need as this poster, but do not have the PEM file as they do:

[soapui soap digital signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474794/soapui-soap-digital-signature)

I do have the local machine certificate that I'd like to sign with on my windows machine that I can see with the certificates snap in to the MMC console.  According to the certificate details, it can be used for digital signing as it contains a private key.

The MMC console will only allow me to export this cert without the private key (understandably).

Does anyone know if it is possible for SoapUI (or any Java based client) to use this certificate for digitally signing requests?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that with soapui there isn't a specific connector to use private keys on windows keystore.

If you want to sign with private keys on windows keystore with java client you can use SUNMSCAPI provider (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI), I give you a code sample:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;

import sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI;

public class WindowsKeystoreSample {

public static final String USER_STORE = "Windows-MY";
public static final String MACHINE_STORE = "Windows-ROOT";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    // instantiate the keystore
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(USER_STORE, new SunMSCAPI());
    keyStore.load(null, null);

    String keyAlias = "key alias";
    // password if you protect the windows keystore... if not null
    char[] password = "somepass".toCharArray();

    Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
    sign.initSign((PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, password));
    sign.update("dateToBeSigned".getBytes());
    byte[] signedData = sign.sign();

}

}
```

Remember that to use sunmscapi you need java version 1.6 or above.

Comment: Thanks for this post.  I've moved past this being an immediate need, but will definitely come back and try this if I have time