# OutGoing WSS not displayed in soap UI

Tags: soapui

as mentioned in "[soapui soap digital signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474794/soapui-soap-digital-signature)"  we should have option to use cert in Aut tab via. OutGoing WSS dropdown but it is not visible to me AND I'M not able to see this option in SOAP UI 3.5.. please advice what could be root cause ?

Comment: It should display not sure why it is not coming ...

Comment: It couldn't hurt to get rid of your obsolete version, and install a newer SoapUI...

Comment: i tried but still it is not coming , is there any setting need to be done ??? tried googling but no reference says any special setting need to be done for this ..

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps in the link provided:
https://www.soapui.org/docs/security-testing/ws-security-settings/

Also, save the Project once the request is configured(except Auth option). Reopen the project and go to Auth section of the request and the value will be available in the OutGoing WSS dropdown.